# MySQL select multi dimensional?

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I would like to select all the posts and their attachments from my database.

This is the structure with dummy data:

**Posts table**

```
id       | post          | userId   | 
---------|---------------|----------|
1        | "hello"       |  1       |
2        | "world"       |  1       |
3        | "ouch"        |  2       |
4        | "test"        |  1       |
```

**Attachments table**

```
id       | postId        | fileName |  time    | 
---------|---------------|----------|----------|
1        | 1             |"hey.jpg" |        0 |
2        | 1             |"test.png"| 53252354 |
3        | 2             |"asd.png" |        0 |
4        | 4             |"asd2.png"|        0 |
```

My code looks like this so far, but I doesn't really get what I'd like to.

```
$qry = $db->prepare('
SELECT p.id
     , p.post
     , p.userId
     , att.fileName
     , att.time
  FROM posts p
  LEFT 
  JOIN attachments att 
    ON att.postId = p.id
');
$qry->execute();
$postsArray = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
[{'id': 1,
'post': 'hello',
'userId': 1,
'attachments': [{'fileName': 'hey.jpg', 'time:' 0}, ... ]
}, ... ]
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: What do you get with your current query?

Comment: To have the result in that sort of format, you will have to simply loop over the actual return data, and build a new array with subarray like that. There is no real 'one query does it' operation to have that format :(

Comment: *"There is no real 'one query does it' operation to have that format "* @IncredibleHat as the expected results are kinda like  valid JSON , MySQL has JSON functions which can [create](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html) JSON .. The question to the topicstarter is do you want to generate JSON on the MySQL server or on the PHP side..

Comment: @RaymondNijland those functions are only in MySQL 5.7.8 and higher

Comment: Hmmm @RaymondNijland ......... ya know... useful information!

Comment: *"those functions are only in MySQL 5.7.8 and higher"* @Nick i know some functions even require 5.7.22+ you can also workaround on lower MySQL versions and use GROUP_CONCAT() and CONCAT() to generate JSON, it's nasty but possible.

Comment: If he needed this output server-side (not in json), he could still build the query results as json, and do a `json_decode` to turn it into a php array. Maybe. Might still need some post processing loop (if not on mysql 5.7.8+). (just checked our production server, and we are not on 5.7.8+ waaa)

Comment: I can't imagine why anyone would choose to do the array parsing in MySQL instead of application code

Comment: @RaymondNijland Actually the MySQL JSON functions still need GROUP_CONCAT to compliment.

Comment: @Strawberry Performance reasons. I've used it a lot.

Comment: *"Actually the MySQL JSON functions still need GROUP_CONCAT to compliment"* with compliment you mean aggregating right? @nl-x you don't need GROUP_CONCAT() to aggregate JSON as MySQL provides *"Two aggregate functions generating JSON values are available. JSON_ARRAYAGG() returns a result set as a single JSON array, and JSON_OBJECTAGG() returns a result set as a single JSON object"* below in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html)

Comment: @RaymondNijland - JSON_*AGG() functions don't support ORDER BY or DISTINCT like GROUP_CONCAT(). So sometimes you still need GROUP_CONCAT().

Comment: *"JSON_*AGG() functions don't support ORDER BY or DISTINCT like GROUP_CONCAT(). So sometimes you still need GROUP_CONCAT()."* @PaulSpiegel i was hoping windowing would work `JSON_ARRAYAGG(<column|expression>) OVER(ORDER BY n ASC)` would worked but i got a error `ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_YET: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'json_arrayagg as window function'` as looking into the error `GROUP_CONCAT()` in the future well not be needed annymore..

Comment: @PaulSpiegel But the work around  simply use a delived table? `SELECT 
 JSON_ARRAYAGG(sorted_values.n)
FROM (
 SELECT 
   a.n
 FROM 
   a  
 ORDER BY 
   a.n
) AS sorted_values` it is not ideal but it works

Comment: @RaymondNijland That’s cool. The first Mysql versions with json support didn’t have those aggregate functions yet. Good to know they’re here now.

Comment: @RaymondNijland ORDER BY in a subquery is too risky. Window functions as workaround is a coding and performance nightmare. There is IMHO no way around `CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(JSON_QUOTE(colName) as CHAR) ORDER BY colName SEPARATOR ','), ']')` for what should be just `JSON_ARRAYAGG(colName ORDER BY colName)`.

Comment: *"ORDER BY in a subquery is too risky"* @PaulSpiegel i tend to agree some modern optimizer might igonre the `ORDER BY` in the subquery (deliverd table) without using a `LIMIT` to change the resultset as required by the ANSI/ISO SQL standards when FETCH was become a part off it what was the year 2008-2011?. Yes `JSON_ARRAYAGG(colName ORDER BY colName)` would be much cleaner syntax and mine choice also..

Comment: Uh, what a discussion is going on here:D Thank you everyone, I've read your comments and saved the new information in my head!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query will give you the right data for the results you want, you can post-process in PHP to get the format you want:

```
foreach ($postArray as $post) {
    $fixed_part = array('id' => $post['id'], 'post' => $post['post'], 'userId' => $post['userId']);
    $key = serialize($fixed_part);
    if (!isset($out[$key])) $out[$key] = $fixed_part;
    $out[$key]['attachments'][] = array('fileName' => $post['fileName'], 'time' => $post['time']);
}
$out = array_values($out);
echo json_encode($out, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output is too long to post but can be seen in this [demo](https://3v4l.org/aAa32). Query results can be seen on [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wU4yh8PCqquXFHQb3K5jmx/0).

Comment: I stick with this solution, after reading it for a few minutes I realised this method might fit the best the current "code-environment".

Answer (score 3):

Usually I would do something like this:

```
$result = $db->query("select id, post, userId from posts");
$posts = [];
while ($post = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJECT)) {
    $post->attachments = [];
    $posts[$post->id] = $post;
}

$result = $db->query("select postId, fileName, time from attachments");
while ($att = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJECT)) {
    $posts[$att->postId]->attachments[] = $att;
    unset($att->postId); // optional
}

$posts = array_values($posts); // optional
echo json_encode($posts);
```

Note that the `$posts` array is id-indexed. I would keep it that way. But if you need exactly the same result as in your question (zero-indexed), you can add this line:

```
$posts = array_values($posts);
```

In newer MySQL versions you can also get the JSON result with a single SQL query:

```
select json_arrayagg(post_json) as json
from (
  select json_object(
    'id', p.id,
    'post', p.post,
    'userId', p.userId,
    'attachments', json_arrayagg(
      json_object('fileName', a.fileName, 'time', time)
    )
  ) as post_json
  from posts p
  left join attachments a on a.postId = p.id
  group by p.id
) x
```

Result:

```
[{"id": 1, "post": "hello", "userId": 1, "attachments": [{"time": 0, "fileName": "hey.jpg"}, {"time": 53252354, "fileName": "test.png"}]}, {"id": 2, "post": "world", "userId": 1, "attachments": [{"time": 0, "fileName": "asd.png"}]}, {"id": 3, "post": "ouch", "userId": 2, "attachments": [{"time": null, "fileName": null}]}, {"id": 4, "post": "test", "userId": 1, "attachments": [{"time": 0, "fileName": "asd2.png"}]}]
```

[db-fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/595S5qUy3D4vk6LnXhNU7F/0)

Comment: Thank you for the help!